# Launch C# WinForm (opened within panel) externally

Tags: c#, winforms

I've never come across this before so I'm not sure if I can even do this in C#.

I've got a WinForm that opens within a panel in the application. Here's the code I use to open every form within the application:

```
public static void OpenForm(System.Windows.Forms.Form formName, bool showAsModal, bool launchInPanel, ref Panel panel)
{
    bool isAlreadyOpen = false;
    foreach (Form form in Application.OpenForms)
    {
        if (form.Text == formName.Text)
        {
            isAlreadyOpen = true;
            form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            form.Focus();
            break;
        }
    }
    if (isAlreadyOpen == false)
    {
        if (!showAsModal)
        {
            if (launchInPanel)
            {
                formName.TopLevel = false;
                formName.AutoScroll = true;
                panel.Controls.Add(formName);
            }
        }
        if (!showAsModal)
            formName.Show();
        else
            formName.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

What I want to do is put a button on any given form that, when clicked by the user, will relaunch that window as a normal WinForm (i.e. not inside the panel). I know I can just write code to close and re-open the form without adding it to a panel, but I presume that would cause the user to lose any info or selections they had entered into that form.

Thoughts?

Comment: I would suggest to use the User Control for this, which is best option in this case. Use the same user control in panel as well as in form. In the user control, create a property which expose/set its values. When you click on the Panel, get user control properties and pass it to the form. In form, set the properties of user control on form load.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'm not actually all that familiar with User Controls. This particular form is a wizard that contains lots of panels which in turn contain lots of different controls. I'm not sure how I could use User Controls to make this better?

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved adding `Button` as follows(dynamically) to a `Form`.

```
var button = new Button {Text = "Show Out"};
button.Click += (o, args) =>
{
    formName.Visible = false;
    if (panel1.Controls.Contains(formName)) // show outside of the parent window
    {
        panel1.Controls.Remove(formName);
        formName.TopLevel = true;
        button.Text = Text = "Show In";     
    }
    else //flip - bring it inside the panel.
    {
        formName.TopLevel = false;
        panel1.Controls.Add(formName);
        button.Text = Text = "Show Out";        
    }
    formName.Show();
};
formName.Controls.Add(button);
```

Not enough information to comment on design, but I suggest consider suggestion explained by @Thakur in comments, probably that's what you want.